# aHow test custom hooks call inside React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have component and inside this component I have
custom hook

```
const Component = () => {
 const { open } = useHook()

return (
  <div> 
     <button onClick={open}/>
  </div>
 )
})
```

Is there any chance to test that open callback that come from useHook has been called after button click in react testing library, something like this

```
  it('Open function is called when we click button', () => {
    render(Component)
    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'))
    // How to test that open has been called?
    expect(open).hasBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

It is easy to test when we pass function as props, but how to test in such case

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you, the problem was just in naming, I needed use mock prefix)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you plan on doing with this information, but this would count the amount of times its been called and set it into state so you can use the info for whatever you need.

```
const Component = () => {
  const { open } = myHook()
 
const handleClick = () => {
  open()
  console.log("open was called")
}

 return (
   <div> 
      <button onClick={handleClick}/>
   </div>
  )
 })
```

Comment: As I mentioned I want to test, that hook open function has been called, when I click button

Comment: I updated it to just console.log a statement whenever the open function is called from the button click

Comment: @Ksenia No, you did not mention anything about clicking the button in your question.

Comment: Pls, explain how your decision is related to testing?Lol

Comment: I see now what you're asking. In the future, please clarify in the description that you are referring to using jest and not just wanting to test it out real fast. I wasnt aware you were trying to write a test for it, thought you just wanted to locally test and see if it worked.

Comment: I suppose that it's not so easy to test(
Sorry, next time will give more detail, just thought it was clear not only for me)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your custom hooks must start with use, For example, useMyHook so that react can figure out a custom hook and apply hook-specific features to it

now you can figure out whether use callback has been called or not

```
let times = 0
const useMyHook = () => {
      const use = () => {
          times += 1
          console.log("use function ran", times) 
      }
      
      return (
         {use: use}
      )
}
```

Comment: im sorry im unable to get what you trying to say , can you be more clear ?

Comment: Ok, I just want to mock open and check that it called when I clicked on button, question related to react testing library/jest